# java.lang.NumberFormatException?

Tags: java, android, numberformatexception

I'm new to android programming.
I have problem in Chat App.
When is send message to any user, user message stores in Firebase Database. But when i try to show all the chats of specific user, it gives me an error.

The problem is java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Here's my Code where im getting error:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder myHolder, int i) {

    //get data
    String message = chatList.get(i).getMessage();
    String timestamp = chatList.get(i).getTimestamp();

    //convert time stamp to dd/mm/yyyy hr:mm am/pm
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(timestamp));
    //cal.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(timestamp));
    String dateTime = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm aa", cal).toString();

    //set Data
    myHolder.messageTv.setText(message);
    myHolder.timeTv.setText(dateTime);

    //msg delivered/seen
    if (i == chatList.size()-1){
        if (chatList.get(i).isSeen()){
            myHolder.isSeenTv.setText("Seen");
        }
        else {
            myHolder.isSeenTv.setText("Delivered");
        }
    }
    else {
        myHolder.isSeenTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bk8f2.png)

Comment: It looks like `timestamp` is `null`. You either to determine why and either fix your code so this doesn't happen or provide error handling to deal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `try-catch` block to handle `NumberFormatException`

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);

try {
    cal.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(timestamp)); 
} catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

String dateTime = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm aa", cal).toString();
```

Comment: Glad to hear that @Patel. Why not then accept the answer?

Comment: @AkshayPatel You should consider showing a message to the user.

Comment: Hey @Akshay-patel, Please accept the answer so that other can find it helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you post full exception stacktrace?
It's possible that this line causes it assuming your timestamp is null

```
Long.parseLong(timestamp)
```